# Избранное в приложении-справочнике

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть приложение-справочник, в нем реализована `SQLite`. Ее я заполняю данными:

- имя
- описание
- категория
- ...
- ссылка на источник в приложении

Нужно в приложение добавить раздел "Избранное" или "Последние посещенные страницы".

Как лучше это реализовать в моей ситуации ?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, вопрос по SQLite или по разделам приложения.

Comment: @TimurVI, планирую анализировать обращения к таблице БД со ссылками, и последние открытые ссылки выводить на экране отдельным списком под названием "Последние посещенные". Да и закладки хорошо бы сделать, но это уже позже. У меня нет опыт в создании подобных вещей, поэтому и обратился сюда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал так.

1. Добавил в таблицу еще одну колонку - `lastViewing`
2. Если пользователь обратился к записи в таблице (то есть прочитал ее), то пишу в `lastViewing` текущую дату в миллисекундах.

```
public void setNewViewing(String description, String currentTime) {
        ContentValues updCV = new ContentValues();
        updCV.put(LT_COL_DATE_TIME, currentTime);
        mSQLiteDB.update(DB_LINKS_TABLE,
                updCV,
                LT_COL_DESC_RU + " =?" + " OR " + LT_COL_DESC_EN + " =?",
                new String[] { description }
        );
}
```

- **description** - строка, по которой производится поиск в таблице
- **currentTime** - текущее время в миллисекундах
- **LT_COL_DATE_TIME** - колонка в таблице
- **LT_COL_DESC_RU** и **LT_COL_DESC_EN** - колонки, в которых производится поиск **description**

А вывод на экран и сортировка реализована через стандартный метод: `Cursor` + `Adapter`. Причем `Cursor` на выходе нужно сделать с обратной сортировкой - самые последние посещения, нужно показать самыми первыми. Ниже основной код запроса для примера.

```
Cursor cursorView = mSQLiteDB.query(
                DB_LINKS_TABLE,
                new String[] {
                        LT_COL_CAT,
                        LT_COL_GRP,
                        LT_COL_DESC_EN,
                        LT_COL_DESC_RU,
                        LT_COL_LINK,
                        LT_COL_DATE_TIME
                },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                // sort ASC and DESC
                // по возрастанию (ASC) или по убыванию (DESC)
                LT_COL_DATE_TIME + " DESC",
                8 // к примеру, отобразить последние 8 посещений
);
```